Custom Named Entity Recognition (NER) Model with spaCy V3
This is my first time building a custom model with SPACY NER.
# Define a function to create spaCy DocBin objects from the annotated data
def get_spacy_doc(file, data):
  # Create a blank spaCy pipeline
  nlp = spacy.blank('en')
  db = DocBin()

  # Iterate through the data
  for text, annot in tqdm(data):
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text)
    annot = annot['entities']

    ents = []
    entity_indices = []

    # Extract entities from the annotations
    for start, end, label in annot:
      skip_entity = False
      for idx in range(start, end):
        if idx in entity_indices:
          skip_entity = True
          break
      if skip_entity:
        continue

      entity_indices = entity_indices + list(range(start, end))
      try:
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode='strict')
      except:
        continue

      if span is None:
        # Log errors for annotations that couldn't be processed
        err_data = str([start, end]) + "    " + str(text) + "\n"
        file.write(err_data)
      else:
        ents.append(span)

    try:
      doc.ents = ents
      db.add(doc)
    except:
      pass

  return db

# Split the annotated data into training and testing sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(cv_data, test_size=0.2)

# Display the number of items in the training and testing sets
len(train), len(test)

# Open a file to log errors during annotation processing
file = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/trained_models/train_file.txt','w')

# Create spaCy DocBin objects for training and testing data
db = get_spacy_doc(file, train)
db.to_disk('/content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/trained_models/train_data.spacy')

db = get_spacy_doc(file, test)
db.to_disk('/content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/trained_models/test_data.spacy')

# Close the error log file
file.close()

# Train a spaCy NER model using the provided configuration and data
!python -m spacy train /content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/config/config.cfg  --output /content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/trained_models/output  --paths.train /content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/trained_models/train_data.spacy  --paths.dev /content/drive/MyDrive/trial_domain_extraction/trained_models/test_data.spacy  --gpu-id 0

Output pipeline:
============================= Training pipeline =============================
ℹ Pipeline: []
ℹ Initial learn rate: 0.001
E    #       SCORE 
---  ------  ------
  0       0    0.00
100     200    0.00
200     400    0.00
300     600    0.00
400     800    0.00
500    1000    0.00
600    1200    0.00
700    1400    0.00
800    1600    0.00

I have followed the following article to the T.text
My pipeline looks empty (please refer above.) Is it because there was too little training data?
I have used 13 entities. Would you suggest training with more amount of annotated data would resolve this issue? If yes, how much quantitatively?
